# how do i loop this adjusted odds ratio function while choosing the first variable from a list of unique variables?

Tags: python, loops

I am seeking to obtain odds ratios for a list of drugs that is adjusted for age and gender. How do i loop this function so that the first predictor cycles through a list of drugs?

```
def a_odds_ratio(df, predictors, response):

    # get treatment variable
    treatment = predictors[0]

    # get predictor and response
    df_pred = df[predictors]
    df_resp = df[response]

    # run glm with binomial family and logit link
    model = sm.GLM(endog=df_resp, exog=sm.add_constant(df_pred, prepend=True),
                    family=sm.families.Binomial(sm.families.links.logit)).fit()

    # summary
    print(model.summary())

    # results
    results = model.conf_int()
    odds_ratios = model.params
    results["odds ratios"] = odds_ratios
    results.columns = ["2.5%", "97.5%", "odds ratios"]
    results = np.exp(results)
    p_values = model.pvalues
    results["p values"] = p_values.round(decimals=3)

    return results

# adjusted odds ratios 
predictors = ["Drug A", "age","gender"]

response = "mortality"

a_odds_ratio(df, predictors=predictors, response=response)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think the question is very clear.

Comment: i'm looking to automate calculation of adjusted odds ratios for a list of drugs, so for predictors = ["Drug A", "age","gender"], predictors = ["Drug B", "age","gender"] etc..

Comment: How is the `list` of predictors stored? Is it a list of lists? Then you can simply loop through it and call the function inside the loop.

Comment: the list of predictors are columns in the data frame.
i tried the following but it didn't work.

a= ['drug a', 'drug b', 'drug c']
for drug in a: 
    print(a_odds_ratio(df, predictors, response))